# Hovering on the date of a comment changes its color to the default link color

Tags: bug, design, meta

When you hover on the post date of a comment on the meta site, the color of the date changes from light gray to bright orange. This is different from the main site and other metas (at least Stack Overflow Meta). The links on the other metas don't change when you hover.

**Edit**:
When the link is visited, the bug doesn’t re-occur.

**Edit 2**:
To fix this, change this CSS rule:

```
a:hover
```

to this:

```
:not(.comment-date)>a:hover
```

Comment: For convenience, here's a comment to test it on ;)